# ROBOCOPY: Suppress all output except PROGRESS BAR

Tags: robocopy

I would like to ask you how I can suppress all text output except the progress bar.

**EXAMPLE CODE**:

> echo [Copying files ...] 
>  robocopy %USERPROFILE%\documents\ USERPROFILE%\desktop\ test_copy.zip /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns

.. with these parameters I get:

> [Copying files ...] 
>  (Blank line) 
>  100% path to file

So, how can I suppress the file name? If I put `/nfl`, then it shows nothing. Any advice?

And second question? How can I delete blank lines from Robocopy?
Only mid-solution, I invented was adding:

> echo | set /p= [Copying files ..]

**Result**:

> [Copying files ...](no blank lines, but new line)
>  100% path
> to file

But, I would like to get this form (no file name, no blank/new line):

> [Copying files ...] 100

%

If you know how to help me, I would really appreciate that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use these switches:

```
/NJH    no job description
/NJS    no job summary
/NFL    no file list
/NDL    no directory list
```

But although that should keep showing progress, for me it does not.

Secondly, to prevent any output (including blank lines) you could use some cmd tricks, like outputing to a temp file and then deleting it:

```bash
robocopy (...) > temp
del temp
```